# gearman works very slow with out of memory

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, gearman

gearmand version 1.1.18 (latest) works very slow when free RAM runs out. I have 64 GB RAM on server and when gearman use all free memory and goes to 1mb of swap - gearmand starts to work very-very slowly. Adding any task to background que can take up to 10 seconds.
Removing task from que can take up to 30 seconds.
Que more than 10 000 000 jobs.

Comment: please add an issue at https://github.com/gearman/gearmand/issues

Comment: This is true for basically all server software that uses a lot of RAM - once the server starts swapping, performance is going to suffer big time.  If your payloads are small but your queue is massive, and you can't process them fast enough, then maybe you need a technology that can use disk instead of RAM - like Apache Kafka.

Comment: Thank you, I added issue to official gearman github - https://github.com/gearman/gearmand/issues/245